# Egg dropping puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm working on [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54cb771c9b30e8b5250011d4) kata on codewars, which is extended version of famous two egg poblem. Goal is to find the critical floor height with given count of eggs and tries, attempts.

I look it for a little bit an find out that critical floor height is equal to sum of binomial coefficients until the given egg and try count:

Sum of Combination **(Tries/i)** where *i* is in range between *1* to *Eggs + 1*.

I use the *comb* function from *scipy.special* with *exact=True* parameter.

For relatively small numbers, like *477 eggs* and *500 tries* or *477 eggs* and *10000 tires*, program calculates very fast, under *0.05* secs. But there are very large checks like *4477 eggs* and *10000 tries*, which takes about 15 secs.

Is my approach wrong or could i done this calculations without getting execution timeout on codewars with this way?

Here is my script:

```
import scipy.special

# n: Eggs m: Tries
def height(n,m):
    ret = sum(scipy.special.comb(m,i, exact=True) for i in range(1,n+1))
    return int(ret)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out instead of using scipy, using loop is more efficient. And implemented this:

```
# n: Eggs m: Tries
def height(n,m):
    if n == 0 or m == 0:
        return 0
    if n > m:
        n = m
    counter,current,total = 1,1,0
    while counter <= n:
        d = (m+1-counter) * current // counter
        total,current,counter = total+d,d,counter+1
    return total
```

It is very fast compared to my previous attempt. On 4477,10000 this takes **0.02 secs** to complete, previous one toke **16.97 secs** to complete.

Answer (score 2):

Since C(N,k) = N! / (k!(N-k)!),

We have C(N,1) = N

And for larger k: C(N,k) = C(N,k-1) * (N-k+1) / k

Calculating C(N,k) is much faster and easier if you start with C(N,k-1).

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it by hand on very small numbers, say *5* and *7*. And let me consider also the case of *0* items out of *7*, whose value is *1* (you can always subtract *1* from the following if you don't want to include it)

- The number of combinations for *0* items out of *7* is `7! / (0! (7-0)!)` => *1*
- The number of combinations for *1* item is `7! / (1! (7-1)!)` => *7*
- *2* items => `7! / (2! (7-2)!)` => *21*. Note we have a new factor *6*, since `(7-2)! * 6 == (7-1)!`, and a new divisor *2* since `1! * 2 == 2!`. At the previous iteration we had a factor *7* and a divisor *1* of course
- *3* items => *35*. New factor *5*, new divisor *3*
- *4* items => *35* again. New factor and new divisor are both *4*
- *5* items => *21* again. Now new factor and new divisor are inverted (*3* and *5*)

Should we continue we would get

- *6* items => *7*
- *7* items => *1*.

So the total number of combinations up to *5* items out of *7* is `1 + 7 + 21 + 35 + 35 + 21` => *120*. Note that if we count up to *7* we get *128*, i.e. `2**7 - 1`

So the simplest code can be:

```
def sum_of_combos(n,k):
    mult = k
    total = 1
    currval = 1
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        currval = (currval * mult) // i
        total += currval
        mult -= 1
    return total

>>> timeit("sum_of_combos(4477,10000)", globals=globals(), number=1000)
17.124391099999997

>>> timeit("sum_of_combos(8477,10000)", globals=globals(), number=1000)     
36.44438840000001
```

Is there room for optimizations? Yes, there is. For instance in the second example above instead of iterating 8477 times we could calculate `2**10000` and then subtract from that the first `(10000 - 8477)` values.